# How to keep your Drupal 8 site synced with 8.x branch

Tags: 8, version-control

Is it practical to both A) develop/maintain a Drupal 8 alpha site and B) keep it up to date with the latest daily/hourly commits from the 8.x branch ?

If so, what would be your strategy to keep your site up to date, while maintaining the integrity/stability of the site itself?  How would you handle commits that affect the database?

My big concern is pulling in commits that affect the database structure.  If the database is affected in a particular commit, I'm assuming the site could easily break.

Comment: FWIW, I have destroyed several sites this way.

Comment: Daily/hourly commits are **not stable**. Actually, anything marked as **alpha is not stable**. Bad commit can destroy your data, and even if it'll be fixed in next commit, lost data is lost. Bad idea. Anyway, always make backups. A lot. And expect crash after each update. Don't expect to maintain stability when using alpha code. Well, some stability may be achieved if you stay with the snapshot you know to be workable, but that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.   I'm wondering if one strategy might be to instead of pulling commits directly - clone a new fresh site with the latest branch and then import the config settings from your previous work (and for content, well - just re-add I guess).

Comment: Nevermind, apparently that feature is still WIP https://drupal.org/node/1613424

Comment: Re-import your configuration wouldn't work even if it would work like that during the alpha phase, because the configuration structure is still being changed, just like the database schema. Until there is a beta release, your only chance is to hope that you can fix any break manually, by reading the issues/commits that break your site and apply the necessary changes manually.

Comment: Last call media is running on Drupal 8 and I asked them a similar question in the comments: http://lastcallmedia.com/node/69/#comment-1175260208

Answer (score 1):

All those comments are correct. While running Drupal 8 for a simple blog, brochureware or similar site is a good idea to test it, doing anything more is most definitely not. Upgrading any code on a production site without testing it first is a bad idea, upgrading it with code which is openly declared to be possibly broken is a spectacularly bad one.

So: build you site, upgrade locally occassionally, be ready to export your content (somehow) and reimport it into the new one (somehow). Neither of these are supported. Writing migrate sources for D8 and a CSV source and target pair would be appreciated and quite possibly would work well for this scenario. You can find me in `#drupal-migrate` on freenode IRC should you want to work on this.